# Laravel 5.1 Socialite default login route

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I try to set the default login path to simply `/auth` and defined it as follows

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $loginPath = '/auth';
    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

I also didn't return anything once the callback is called because I thought I already defined it as above. What am I missing? Rightnow if I want to access page dashboard directly type URL on browser, Laravel will bring me to page `/auth/login`

Answer (score 0):

the above code is for social authentication . 
the reason that you are always redirected is that you aren't logged in to your application .

if you want to use social auth to login to your app you should handle in handleProviderCallback() .
if not you should follow laravel authentication mechanism .

I think this will help you .
http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication

Comment: how to make social user logged in to Laravel apps. I consult many times to the docs